# Apache Benchmark is not writing error in the log file

Tags: php, apache

Apache Benchmark is not writing error in the log file.

I tried this `ab -n1000 -c10 http://localhost`.

My error log file is located in `/var/log/apache/error.log`

Please help.

Comment: Hi Sahal, I've fixed the spelling in your question.  In the future, please do not use "plz", it's not proper English.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But if can provide the answer it will be more helpful :).

Comment: I can configure some other ErrorLog with ab command  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you seeing an error in ab itself or in your apache server ? ab prints results to stdout and you have options for csv(-e) or gnuplot(-g)

Comment: produces output in comma separated value format for ease of further processing. run ab -h for more details.